# Why doesn't this code log out the appropriate result

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, selection-sort

I'm trying to implement a sorting visualizer in React. I have a button which on click calls a selectionSort() function:

```
selectionSort() {
    var arr = this.state;
    console.log(arr);
    var n = arr.length;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      var min = i;
      for (j = i; j < n; ++j) {
        if (arr[min] > arr[j]) {
          min = j;
        }
      }

      var temp = arr[min];
      arr[min] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = temp;
    }
    console.log("new array", arr);
  }
```

However, the second console.log() is supposed to give the sorted array right? It doesn't, and I can't figure out what happened.

Comment: you will get sorting logic on google. Just use it in your code

Comment: That wasn't the problem, I just had to use `var arr = this.state.array;` instead of `var arr = this.state;` Anyway thanks @VishalPawar

Comment: Are you trying to mutate `this.state` in reactjs directly? This is really not recommended as `this.state` is immutable, try making a copy of it before sorting.

Comment: please do **not** set react states like you did. You should always make use of `setState` to do so. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Comment: @HaoWu, I didn't know that. Anyway I was just trying whether the algorithm would work. Thanks for your input, will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem here, working fine at my end.

```js
function selectionSort() {
    var arr = [1,2,4,5,6,3,10,9];
    console.log(arr);
    var n = arr.length;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      var min = i;
      for (j = i; j < n; ++j) {
        if (arr[min] > arr[j]) {
          min = j;
        }
      }
      var temp = arr[min];
      arr[min] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = temp;
    }
    console.log("new array", arr);
  }
```

Comment: but you have got an hardcoded array here and the OP has got a react state. React states should not be set without `setState`.

Comment: You are right, but he was having issue getting a sorted array after the loop in console.log.

Comment: Just had to use `this.state.array` while assigning to arr

Comment: @KarthikRaj read the comments under your question. this is very important